# .NET memory management

Tags: .net, memory-management

Could someone provide a very high-level overview of .NET memory management?

More specifically I'm looking for an overview of memory management..

- is there an overall .net heap?
- are heaps application based?
- when I run my application is a new heap created/memory allocated or is the memory from the overal .net heap?
- what happens when the .net heap runs out of its original memory? does it request more from OS?
- the basics would be a great start for me to then go-on and read more

Comment: Garbage Collection: Automatic Memory Management in the Microsoft .NET Framework - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/bb985010.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each process has its own heap - and if more memory is needed after the GC has cleaned up everything it can, the process asks the OS for more information.

The best resource I know about for this sort of information is Jeffrey Richter's [CLR via C#](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735627045) book.

Comment: So .net itself doesnt have a default or overall allocation of memory? Just my application (process) does when its run, and if more memory is required after the GC has done its thing, more memory is requested from the OS? Am I on the correct lines of thinking, that if at this point the OS cant provide anymore memory to my process then a (OOM) out of memory exception is sent back?

Comment: @user799372: I don't believe there are any default limits, no (unlike Java, say). I believe a CLR hosting environment could enforce one if it wanted to. And yes, you'll get an OOM if there isn't enough memory to satisfy your app.

Comment: on my processes created heap, does this have a default limit? or is the limit calculated once my process has started and the heap has been 'tuned' to my processes needs as so to speak? then objects within the heap get shuffled by the GC into correct generations based on their attributes and object size?

Comment: @user799372: Not sure what you mean - do you mean how hard the GC will work to clear existing memory before it requests more? I believe that may well change based on different CLR versions, but I *think* it's dynamic - it will adjust itself based on previous behaviour.

Comment: i just wondered if when a process is created, its accompanying heap had an overall size limit (which in turn triggers a GC upon thresh-hold breach)

Comment: @user799372: Well it's clearly set up with *some* sort of heap size, but I don't know what that size is by default... and it's not really a "limit" as such, just "the current size".

Comment: that makes sense :) ive just read most desktop apps will use concurrent GC mode; other than the GC being triggered by request for more memory in heap, what else causes the GC to be triggered?

Comment: @user799372: I *believe* that memory pressure *from other applications* will also cause a GC in some cases, but I'm not entirely sure.

Comment: Could you provide a basic overview of the stack? does this exist within the heap? or is the stack a seperate section of memory created as well as the heap for a process? I understand usually the stack is for value types and the heap for reference types (though not always the case, but mostly?) ps thanks for your help Jon

Comment: @user799372: This goes well beyond what can reasonably be done in comments. I suggest you read Eric Lippert's series of blog posts about the stack. See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/04/27/the-stack-is-an-implementation-detail.aspx

Comment: Thanks Jon, I'll give that a read and also your page too on the topic http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/memory.html :) thanks again for your time

Answer (score 1):

> is there an overall .net heap?

There are many.  The ones you normally care about are the generation 0, 1 and 2 garbage collected heaps, the Large Object Heap and the loader heap.  Generations help make the garbage collector more effective.  The LOH is used for objects that are too large to move around.  The loader heap stores static variable values.

> are heaps application based?

No, they are AppDomain based.  AppDomains provide a cheap alternative to a process.

> when I run my application is a new heap created/memory allocated or is the memory from the overal .net heap?

The default CLR creates the primary AppDomain with its associated heaps before your code starts running.

> what happens when the .net heap runs out of its original memory? does it request more from OS?

Yes.

Comment: Are app domains created automatically or is this something we have to define/build into our apps?

Comment: Pointed out in the 3rd answer: the default CLR automatically creates the primary AppDomain.  Others will require code.

Comment: Ah you did say that - sorry I misread :) soo.. When a process is created, the primary appdomain is too. If we want more appdomains, code is required. How do we know which process to add our subsequent appdomains too? Is this just something we should know, for instance, we'd of probably made app1:process1 & would already be aware of its existence, thus can programatically add a second, third etc appdomain to that particular process?

Comment: I can't help notice that these follow-up questions are perhaps a bit misplaced.  Why don't you ask the guy whose answer you accepted?

Comment: Im new to stackoverflow so still getting to grips with how to discuss appropriately :) i think id already accepted the previous answer before your reply. Id luv to give you both the answer as youve both been great in helpin me learn more about the question, but i dont think it lets me do that

Answer (score 0):

I have covered the following questions in this article on .net memory management. I hope this gives readers a good idea of .net memory management.

1. How memory is allocated to value types?
2. How memory is allocated to reference types?
3. How memory is allocated to static fields and global variables?
4. How memory is allocated in multithreaded environment?
5. How memory is allocated in inheritance?
6. How GC works?
7. What are Memory Management best practices?

Let us begin
Memory allocation of .net types happens either in stack or heap. We need to understand when does a type be allocated in stack or heap.

**STACK**

All the local variables in a method are allocated memory in STACK.
When a method A calls another method B, return address of calling method A is stored in STACK and the control is passed to method B.
Once method B execution is complete, it is (along with its local data) removed from STACK and execution resumes from where it stopped in method A.

**HEAP**

Before we check what is stored in heap, we need to understand the root reference.
Let us understand that using an example –

Let us say there is an employee class which contains list of employee skills. If we need to access the employee’s skills, we need create an object of employee class and then access that list.

So here object reference of type employee is the root reference which is stored on STACK and actual object is stored on heap

All global variables, static global variables and types (when initialized using new) are stored in a HEAP.

**MEMORY ALLOCATION IN A MULTI-THREADED ENVIRONMENT**
Every thread has its own STACK, but HEAP is shared among all threads. So, it becomes important to ensure thread safety in case of HEAP because different threads can access/modify same resource.

Thread safety is out of scope in this document.

**MEMORY ALLOCATION IN INHERITANCE**
When we create object of a child class, single object is created in heap.
This object would hold all state related data of classes including the parent class.

**GARBAGE COLLECTION (GC)**
.net uses garbage collection for automatic cleanup of allocated objects.

Garbage collector checks allocated objects on heap which are not referenced by anything or we may say which do not have a root reference.

Static Variables are allocated on heap and are never garbage collected because these never have root references.

GC runs on a separate thread for collecting the unused objects and free up memory. It runs automatically periodically or when application begins to run out of memory.

A developer can for GC to run by executing GC.Collect(), but it is not advisable to do so as it may hamper application performance.

**GC GENERATIONS**

Based on the object’s lifetime, it could be categorized into 3 categories –

Generation 0 – when the object is just created, it is put in Generation 0. It means this object is new and has not been checked by GC yet.

Generation 1 – object which is inspected by GC once, but survived because of having a root reference is put in Generation 1.

Generation 2 – objects which pass two or more inspections and are not killed by GC because of having a root reference are in Generation 2.

GC does not collect objects of unmanaged resources like file, network, database, UI elements.
We need to use Dispose explicitly (IDisposable) or use the concerned class object within using statement (make sure IDiposable is inherited in the type we want to use dispose for).

**MEMORY MANAGEMENT BEST PRACTICES**

1. Use IDisposable or using statement to release unmanaged resources.
2. Try to defer the initialization of members of class if those are not required during creation of the class object.
3. Collections such as List sets the initial size to 4 elements if no size is defined during list creation. And if we add any element after 4, the collection size is doubled in memory.
   So, to avoid such situation and not take extra memory when list is small, it is recommended to specify the initial size of the collection.
4. Try to keep the data model simple and well structured. Because if it is too complex, GC would take more time in analyzing the whole graph to check which objects can be collected.
5. Make use of yield statement when possible.
   Yield keyword in C# is used to generate iterator pattern which is an IEnumerator implementation. The benefit of using yield statement is that the whole collection does not need to be in memory. It processes one item at a time.
6. Avoid excessive grouping or aggregate functions in LINQ queries.

THANK YOU!